# Files ti include in wordpress so that defined terms works?

Tags: wordpress

What are the files needed to include in wordpress so that all the defined terms and function works in user created folder inside the wordpress theme folder?

Note: I have created a folder inside *wp theme folder* and I want to use `wp_insert_post()`function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should Include the `wp-load.php` in external file to access the Wordpress functions.

Note: There may be  better solution for you instead of creating external file inside theme.

Comment: Is wp-load.php is renamed to wp-includes/load.php. Since I cannot find wp-load.php. But can only find load.php inside wp-includes folder.

Comment: wp-load will be in root. load.php and wp-load.php is not same